# Рисование растушеванной или полупрозрачной кистью

Tags: delphi

Мой вариант - это просчитывать цвет каждого будущего пиксела нахождением среднего цвета между цветом фона и цветом кисти (чтобы получался плавный (растушеванный) переход от линии кисти к фону). Но это отнимает много процессорного времени.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не совсем уверен, но попробуйте поиграться с `Pen.Mode`. Особо присмотритесь к `pmXor` и `pmNotXor`

```
  Canvas.Pen.Mode := pmBlack;{, pmWhite, pmNop, pmNot, pmCopy, pmNotCopy,
    pmMergePenNot, pmMaskPenNot, pmMergeNotPen, pmMaskNotPen, pmMerge,
    pmNotMerge, pmMask, pmNotMask, pmXor, pmNotXor}
```